# Implementing a Map to count character frequency

Tags: java, dictionary, character, frequency

Basically I'm trying to implement a map using a String as the key (single character) and an integer variable (character frequency).

I get inaccurate frequencies when the program runs.
Does anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class WordCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        File f1 = new File("article.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(f1).useDelimiter("|");

        Map<String, Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        String letter;
        Integer value = 0;

        while(scan.hasNext()){

            letter = scan.next();

            if(wordMap.containsKey(letter)) wordMap.put(letter, value++);

            else wordMap.put(letter, new Integer(value++));
        }
        System.out.println(wordMap);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem is here:

```
while(scan.hasNext()){
    letter = scan.next();

    if(wordMap.containsKey(letter)) wordMap.put(letter, value++);  // problem

    else wordMap.put(letter, new Integer(value++));
}
```

The if statement should look like this:

```
if (wordMap.containsKey(letter)) {
    Integer prev = wordMap.get(letter);
    wordMap.put(letter, prev++);
}  else {
    wordMap.put(letter, 1);
}
```

Though, to be a bit better, you would just want to do one lookup on the map, like this:

```
Integer prev = wordMap.get(letter);
if (prev == null) {
    wordMap.put(letter, 1);
}  else {
    wordMap.put(letter, prev++);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this bit is wrong

```
    Integer value = 0;

    while(scan.hasNext()){

        letter = scan.next();

        if(wordMap.containsKey(letter)) wordMap.put(letter, value++);

        else wordMap.put(letter, new Integer(value++));
    }
```

should be

```
    while(scan.hasNext()){

        letter = scan.next();

        //get current count
        int value;
        if(wordMap.containsKey(letter)){
            value = wordMap.get(letter);
        }else {
            value = 0;
        }
        // increment count
        value++;
        wordMap.put(letter, value);
    }
```

putting a value into a map or anything else does not reset it, 
or magically resynchronise the property to what we want(at least in java it doesn't)
so we have to aquire the value from the map each time we want to modify it.

Otherwise all we are doing is placing a random value in the map. In your version what you would have is the character count when the last instance of the letter was encountered.